# How do I use ParaView's CSVReader in a Python Script?

Tags: python, csv, paraview

How do I use ParaView's CSVReader in a Python Script? An example would be appreciated.

Comment: As you have more reputation than the usual suspect, I guess you know that this question should be improved to at least show what you've done so far and where you got stuck (i.e. why you didn't RTFM).

Comment: I did read the manual, but the manual doesn't have an example. I just figured it out by doing some guessing and checking, which is what I expected would happen. If someone who knows more than me will provide an answer, then that's great. If not, then I'll answer it myself and hopefully save someone else from doing the guessing and checking that I just went through.

Comment: The manual is not clear with this respect. Is clear to import with GUI but in python script is not clear enough. For that reason I upvote and provide my way to achieve that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a .csv file that looks like this:

```
x,y,z,attribute
0,0,0,0
1,0,0,1
0,1,0,2
1,1,0,3
0,0,1,4
1,0,1,5
0,1,1,6
1,1,1,7
```

then you can import it with a command that looks like this:

```
myReader = CSVReader(FileName='C:\foo.csv', guiName='foo.csv')
```

Also, if you don't add that `guiName` parameter, you can change the name later using the `RenameSource` command like this:

```
RenameSource(proxy = myReader, newName = 'MySuperNewName'
```

Credit for the renaming part of this answer to [Sebastien Jourdain](http://www.paraview.org/pipermail/paraview/2012-June/025184.html).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't know Paraview at all. But I found "...  simply record your work in the desktop application in the form of a python script ..." at their site. If you import a CSV like that, it might give you a hint.

Comment: That sounds like a great way to learn and I'm sure I'll do that in the future. However, the code that's generated seems to be a little different than what's actually run because the guiName doesn't get set when I run that Macro.

Comment: Record your work in the desktop application by clicking the menu item "Tools > Start Trace". After you do some stuff that gets recorded, you can save it as a python (.py file) and then load it as a macro.

Answer (score 1):

Improving the @GregNash's answer. If you want to include only a single file (called `foo.csv`):

> outcsv = CSVReader(FileName= 'foo.csv')

Or if you want to include all files with certain pattern use `glob`. For example if files start with string `foo` (aka foo.csv.0, foo.csv.1, foo.csv.2):

> myreader = CSVReader(FileName=glob.glob('foo*'))

To use glob is neccesary `import glob` in the preamble. In general in Filename you could work with strings generated with python which could contain more complex pattern files and file's path.